# ImportError when I run Jupyter notebook with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to run a .ipynb notebook in VSCode, but it fails and sends this message.
Note that in the browser I can run everything without problems.

````
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\Users\Marta\anaconda3\envs\geo_env\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.21.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found.```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with the `numpy` you are using. Could you try to reinstall it?

```
pip uninstall -y numpy

pip uninstall -y setuptools

pip install setuptools

pip install numpy
```